# Why is kapparos gender specific while a Korban Chattas for an individual is a female?

Tags: minhag, women, korban, men-male, kaparah-atonement

There is a Minhag brought in SA OC [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14166&st=&pgnum=143&hilite=) to take a chicken on Erev Yom Kippur & perform Kapparos with it. The custom is for a man to take a male chicken while a woman chooses a female chicken to perform the ritual. However, during the times of the Beis Hamikdash, when an individual would bring a Korban Chattas as an atonement for a sin, he/she would always sacrifice a female. See [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=54045&st=&pgnum=30&hilite=). Why the difference? Both are being done to atone for a sin?

Comment: A king who sinned would bring a male goat. But both are being done to atone for a sin?

Comment: The kapparos brought before Tom kipur are not a Marvin nor are they governed by Halacha relevant to karbonos.

Answer (score 2):

Because it's not just atonement, but substitution (תמורה). See the teshuvah of the Geonim quoted in [Tur Orach Chaim 605](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x2679), and Bach there.

Comment: The actual phrasing there ואין
 אנו יודעין מנהג זה למה אי משום תמורה implies that Temurah is a possible suggestion which needed an explanation, it was not a definitive explanation. Especially since he started off calling it a kapara  א יש מקומות שנוהגין לשחוט תרנגול
 לכפרה and repeated that language later.

Comment: @user6591 that's the questioner's statement. The answer mentions שעושין תמורה אילים, and the Bach clarifies that the intent is דלעולם המנהג הוא משום תמורה.